# How to install numpy with pip+mingw in windows?

Tags: windows, numpy, mingw, pip

I have got pip+mingw working in windows. I tested it with

```
pip install cython
```

and it works perfectly.

```
pip install numpy
```

fails however with a long list of error messages.  What is the correct way to do this or should I give up trying with pip?

```
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Running from numpy source directory.
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1503: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1506: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1419: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1422: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_info:

  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



running egg_info

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

building library "npymath" sources

No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Running from numpy source directory.

c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\marshall\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-marshall\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1503: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\clifford\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-clifford\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1506: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\clifford\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-clifford\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\clifford\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-clifford\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1419: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\clifford\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-clifford\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1422: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: i think you just need pip install numpy (without the .exe)   you should install pip first.

Comment: read this doc it's helpful http://sunpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/installation/win.html

Comment: I have pip but it fails when trying to install numpy.

Comment: DistUtils can seems to try to compile with Visual. Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc/16740123#16740123

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 5):

pip is building Numpy from source and that's quite an undertaking. The failure at the end tells me that you may not have your compiler properly configured for distutils. I use the Windows SDK compiler myself: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

If you use this one, you should define the environment variables:

```
set MSSdk=1
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
```

Having said that, it's much easier to install Numpy and Scipy using one of the .msi installers which you can find here: http://scipy.org/Download.
Numpy relies on the BLAS linear algebra libraries and the build of those is highly technical and a build of Numpy from source on Windows is best avoided unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: I would like to fix the distutils problem at least. I can pip install cython. Is there some other test I can do to check if that is really a problem?