# Rectangle Example, cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have problems getting the cython rectangle example to work. http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

I have created my **setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rect.pyx",            # our Cython source
       sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

**Rectangle.h**

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
        int x0,y0,x1,y1;
        Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getLength();
        int getHeight();
        int getArea();
        void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
}
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace shapes;

Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1){
    x0 = X0;
    y0 = Y0;
    x1 = X1;
    y1 = Y1;
}

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {

}

int Rectangle::getLength() {
    return (x1-x0);
}


int Rectangle::getHeight()
{
    return (y1 - y0);
}

int Rectangle::getArea()
{
    return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
}

void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy)
{
    x0 += dx;
    y0 += dy;
    x1 += dx;
    y1 += dy;
}
```

**rect.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int)
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getLength()
        int getHeight()
        int getArea()
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr   # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

Now when ever I run

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace

I receive

```
running build_ext
building 'rect' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c rect.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rect.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Rectangle.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Rectangle.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rect.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Rectangle.o -o /media/psf/dfki/test/rect.so
unable to execute c++: No such file or directory
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

I do not know why and tried to search for it but could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.
Gohu

Comment: What is your c++ toolchain installation currently? Is it accessible from your `PATH` settings? (looks like you have GCC, and need to call `g++` instead of `c++`).

Comment: Hi, wow thank you very much. This helped alot ur hint. I was able to search for and yes the solution is the same as here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc