# Compiling cython's HelloWorld Example: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, cython, cythonize

Whenever I try to compile the simpleset cython example

helloworld.pyx

```
print "Hello World"
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

I am receiving

```
c:\> python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=c:\cygwin64\bin\gcc
running build_ext
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'c:\cygwin64\bin\gcc' compiler
```

What could I have done wrong?

P.S. I am using

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: This might be relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737696/5781248

Comment: Your python code seems to be in version 2, while you have python 3.6 installed. But for the root of your problem, i don't know

Comment: you are on Windows ? Can you provide more information about your OS, your compiler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know  Cython, but you can do the following:
Add c:\cygwin64\bin\ to `PATH`. Then, instead of:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=c:\cygwin64\bin\gcc
```

run:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Answer (score 3):

Specifying compiler `--compiler=` for `cython` is very tricky. I have the same problem on Ubuntu.
The right command that shows no errors is

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```