# Cross Compiler for python for ARM architecture on X86 architecture on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, arm, ubuntu-16.04, cross-compiling

I am currently working on architectural simulators and want to know how to install a cross compiler for ARM arch for Python language on X86 architecture on OS ubuntu 16.04
I already have installed the ARM toolchain of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
But these are for c and C++ respectively. How do I compile python programs for ARM ISA

Thanks in advance
Nirmol Munvar

Comment: didnt know you could compile python to a real isa...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to compile a Python extension written in C/C++ for ARM using the cross compiler, please look at a similar question here: [How to tell distutils to use gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737260/how-to-tell-distutils-to-use-gcc).