# How to fix error: Cygwin gcc cannot be used with --compiler=mingw32

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cygwin, setuptools

I'm trying to install this project: https://github.com/drufat/triangle. Unfortunatly, I get the following error:

```
error: Cygwin gcc cannot be used with --compiler=mingw32
```

I'm using the lastest version of gcc for Cygwin on Windows 7 64 bit and I'm trying to install that project for python 3.7.1. It's seems to come from my distutil configuration. My `distutils.cfg` file contains:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

I tried that solution but it doens't helped: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740123/5075502

Comment: The linked solution is outdated. `distutils` in Python 3 was changed due to [Issue #12641](https://bugs.python.org/issue12641). See [commit 6a9c0e5](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6a9c0e50a9d0e09011f59e7eca060473141e8f43). Try `--compiler=gcc` or `--compiler=g++`.

Comment: I solved my problem by installing the unofficial python package https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem occured. I fixed it by changing `mingw32` by `gcc` like @phd said.

Answer (score 1):

The `gcc` options to build for `MinGW64` is no longer supported by the regular cygqin compiler `gcc`, aka `x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc`. Instead, you should also install the `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` package which provides the `GCC for Win64 toolchain (C, OpenMP)`. This will also install other packages (through dependencies) which provide compatible `binutils`, `headers`, `libraries`, and `runtime`.

In your Makefile or compiler command line, replace `gcc` with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`. This will allow you to compile and link executables which do not depend on the `cygwin1.dll`.

Comment: Works great, and if you need to compile C++ make sure to install mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++